# How to find the path to the executable of a program

Tags: vb.net, winforms, registry, registrykey

In a VB.NET application I need to set a button to start a program - specifically, Steam. But I need to allow for the user having installed the program somewhere other than the default location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam". So all I know is the executable name: "steam.exe".

In searching for an answer it looks like I should be able to get the path using Microsoft.Win32.Registry somehow, but the examples I'm seeing aren't helping me (I guess I'm just not getting how to apply those examples to my situation).

[This tutorial](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/regprogpath.htm) gives the example of finding the path to the excel executable:

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppPaths\excel.exe")
Dim path As String = regKey.GetValue("Path").ToString
```

But I'm getting a value of "Nothing" for regKey. Not only that, even if it did get a value for `regKey`, how would I know the registry path for another program (Steam, in my case)?

And how much will the version of Windows change the possible registry location of a program - if at all?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but an alternative route in case you get no help. You could set up a Try-Catch for opening the default location. If it doesn't find it, it'll throw an error you can catch. There you can inform the user you "can't find Steam.exe, please speificy", then create an OpenFileDialog and have them locate it. You can save this setting numerous ways, along with a boolean that you check that says it's a custom directory whenever they click the button again.

Comment: Thanks, Keith - that looks like a good alternative. I'll keep that in mind if I don't get a way to find the reg key.

Comment: HKCU.Steam.Shell.Open.Command

Comment: @Plutonix - That gives me the value `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Steam\steam.exe" "%1"` `Process.Start` errors on that as is, but I guess I could use some string manipulation to strip off the end. Other programs that have `shell\open\command` also have something similar tacked on to the end of the path. I don't believe that is the **best** way...

Comment: You seem to be looking for a generic way to magically pluck from the Registry any path for any app at any time.  I don't think you'll find it.  You _must_ know _something_ about what you are looking for.  The registry path, for one thing.  It could be under `App_Paths`, but no guarantee.  Best to check `Classes Root` for its entry.  `LOCAL_MACHINE` is notoriously permissions sensitive.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - Yes, I guess that's what I was leaning towards, but I'm seeing now that that's probably not the best approach. For now I'm going with Keith's suggestion of using a try/catch and letting the user set the path if the default isn't found.